# attr data-bind for an observable does not update in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have bound an observable from my view model to the title of a div like so:

area is a ko.observable()

When the value is set the first time, the title updates correctly. Any further updates to area do not result in a title update.
I know that the value sets properly because I added a span bound to the same and that updates just fine:

Not sure what I am missing.

Update: Sorry, I guess I was doing a stupid thing. I was using the jQueryUI modal dialog and instead of setting the title of the dialog, I was setting the containing div title...which of course, is wrong.

Comment: Post html markup and view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, 
http://jsfiddle.net/R8fCF/

```
<div data-bind="attr: {title: area }">Hover for title</div>

ViewModel = function() {
    this.area = ko.observable(0);
    setInterval(function() {
        this.area(this.area() + 1);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```